# NSolve connot solve my equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve
$$\left(\frac{hc}{k_B} - 5x\right)e^{hc/k_Bx} + 5x = 0,$$
where $h = 6.626 \times 10^{-34}$, $k = 1.381 \times 10^{-23}$ and $c = 3 \times 10^8$. My code is

```
h = 6.626*^-34; k = 1.381*^-23; c = 3*^8;
NSolve[((h c)/k - 5 x) Exp[(h c)/k x] + 5 x == 0, x]
```

but Mathematica doesn't solve the equation, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Restrict the domain to `Reals`, i.e., `NSolve[((h c)/k - 5 x) Exp[(h c)/k x] + 5 x == 0, x, Reals]` This will find both roots `{{x -> -0.446495}, {x -> 0.447935}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
h = 6.626*^-34; k = 1.381*^-23; c = 3*^8;
FindInstance[((h c)/k - 5 x) Exp[(h c)/k x] + 5 x == 0, x, Reals]
```

giving

```
{{x -> -0.446495}}
```

or use:

```
FindRoot[((h c)/k - 5 x) Exp[(h c)/k x] + 5 x == 0, {x, -0.4}]
```

which gives the same result.